# Как узнать дефолтный скрипт скролла экрана в браузере

Tags: javascript

Я отключаю скролл в своей функции и мне необходимо переназначить скролл, но при использовании scrollBy страница дергается

```js
$(opportunities).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event) {
  delta = parseInt(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail);
  let height = window.pageYOffset;
  if (delta >= 0) {
    console.log('Вверх');
    event.preventDefault(); //опустошим стандартную обработку
      var id  = $(header), //заберем айдишник блока с параметром URL
          top = $(id).offset().top; //определим высоту от начала страницы до якоря
      $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500); 
  } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      window.scroll(0, this.scrollTop + 100);
  }
});
```

Comment: Можете конкретизировать вопрос? А лучше с примером. Вы хотите получить положение скролла? Отключить скролл браузерный и поставить свой в тоже положение? Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы при скроле вверх страница плавно прокручивалась на верхний блок, а при скролле вниз был дэфолтный скролл(добавил код)

Comment: оооочень плохая идея менять нативный скрол браузера. На многих устройствах уже есть плавный скрол, инерционный скрол, и при взаимодействии с такой самодеятельностью странице становится невозможно пользоваться, на экране творится кромешный ад. Пожалейте пользователей

Comment: Плавный скролл при переходе к якорю - это ладно. Но только не ручной скролл